# How to insert a word into a URL on form input submit

Tags: append

I would like to have a text input in a form for a user to enter a random word and have it appended at the end of this URL where the word "man" is? Then, the user would click the button to go to the complete URL... Any thoughts? php would be nice.

https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/man.mp3

Comment: Need you to please edit your question. Are you writing this in PHP or just asking if that is needed? Is this javascript? Or do you only have the HTML? There are many ways to make HTML forms, and many ways to do what you're asking. We need more details about your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think redirect can be one of the solutions. I assume that you can use php.

First, pass your input by POST to your page's URL.

Second, in the header of your page, check POST data and redirect to your target URL.

```
<?php if($_POST) {
    $word=$_POST['word'];
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' 
        content='0; url=https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/$word.mp3' />";
?>
```